# Beamer class identifies table as figure when using subcaption

Tags: beamer, cleveref

The Tex Version in my office was recently updated and I am having trouble getting everything back in order. Specifically, I want to use the `subcaption` package, which seems to mark tables as figures. Here's a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Results in \autoref{tab:tab}, \autoref{fig:fig-a}--\ref{fig:fig-b}, \autoref{fig:fig}.
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
a & b
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table Caption}\label{tab:tab}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{Subfigure caption}\label{fig:fig-a}
\includegraphics[trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{Subfigure caption}\label{fig:fig-b}
\includegraphics[trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure caption}\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the table captioned as Table 1 and the figure as Figure 1. What I get is the table marked as Figure 1 and the figure is Figure 2.

On a related note, `autoref` doesn't work here, as I get the warning:

```
hyperref package loaded with implicit=false option -disabling cleveref's hyperref support.
```

Both these issues are resolved if I change the `documentclass` to `article` (and remove the `\begin{frame}`and `\end{frame}`), but of course I want to be able to use `beamer`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The table is well identified as a table (it is counted separately from the figure) however as `\autoref` does not work here, you have to provide the prefixes yourself. Note that despite the warning, `\cref` seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks @BambOo, `\Cref` seems to do the trick.
There was a problem in the LaTeX update installation on just my machine that caused the table to be counted as figure, but that has been resolved now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments